# Blurry font issue on iPad Safari

Tags: css, font-face, ipad-2

I'm using @font-face to load the web fonts which is loading correctly:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLight';
src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeueLight/helveticaneuelight.eot');
src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeueLight/helveticaneuelight.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/HelveticaNeueLight/helveticaneuelight.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/HelveticaNeueLight/helveticaneuelight.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/HelveticaNeueLight/helveticaneuelight.svg#HelveticaNeueLight') format('svg');

font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant:normal;
```

}

I also have another class to style and bold the text:

```
.BusinessLeftHeader{
    font-family: HelveticaNeueLight;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding: 30px 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1;
    font-variant: normal;    
}
```

Now, the problem is that font is not looking bold on iPad 2. It looks like text is showing with blurry effect or something like this.

I also have use this code to fix this problem.

```
-moz-font-smoothing: none;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

But again, still getting same problem. Text is not looking good on iPad 2. When I zoom in, it looks fine.

Comment: try giving your containers even widths and heights like if if width is 423px then make it 424px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few considerations here, firstly you have conflicting style settings:

```
-moz-font-smoothing: none;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

They should all be set to either `antialiased` or `none`.

You also state you wish to have a bold font, however you have not set the `font-weight` style and are using a font called `HelveticaNeueLight` which I imagine by its very name, is not bold nor include a bold version. At the least you will need to set:

`font-weight:bold`

Additionally, the issue is likely that the custom font you are using is not packaged with a bold version. In such instances a browser will typically 'interpret' how it should render a bold version using the available typeface, producing unexpected results. You may want to either include a bold version of the font or reference a specific weight if one is included.